# Convert Asp:GridView To RadGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, radgrid, radgridview

I have been using this syntax for my asp:gridview and I am attempting to convert it to a RadGridView now.

I get an error of

> Unable to cast object of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridBoundColumn' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'.'

On this -

> DataControlField

How should this syntax be changed to work with a RadGrid?

```
    private int GetColumnIndexRad(Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid grid, string colName)
    {
        foreach (DataControlField col in grid.Columns)
        {
            if (col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() == colName.ToLower().Trim())
            {
                return grid.Columns.IndexOf(col);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use GridView's `DataControlField` instance in Telerik's `RadGrid` because they're using different naming to define grid elements (columns, rows, etc.).

Try iterating `MasterTableView.Columns` collection to find column index based on column name:

```
private int GetColumnIndexRad(Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid grid, string colName)
{
    foreach (GridColumn column in grid.MasterTableView.Columns)
    {
        if (column.UniqueName.ToLower().Trim() == colName.ToLower().Trim())
        {
            return column.OrderIndex - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

NB: If `RadGrid.MasterTableView.Columns` doesn't work, try alternatives like `RadGrid.MasterTableView.AutoGeneratedColumns` or `RadGrid.MasterTableView.RenderColumns`.

Similar issue: [Get Column Index in RadGrid](https://www.telerik.com/forums/current-column-index#Id60dV4GrEuGrzRWzXb44Q)